# The Term "Cofinal"

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I was reading about ordered fields $\mathbb{F}$ with countable cofinality which means that there is a countable set $S$ that is cofinal. The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)) of $S$ being cofinal is that for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ there exists $s \in S$ such that $s \geq a$.

I was wondering about the meaning of the name "cofinal". It seems (at least to me) that it would imply that there is such a notion as a "final" subset. Oddly enough, the dual notion seems to be that of a coinitial subset (just switch the direction of the inequality in cofinality).

I was just wondering if anyone knew if there was any meaning to the "co-". I looked around on Wikipedia and did not really find anything. The closed that I came was the definition of an [initial/lower set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set). So, I suppose that to dualize the definition of initial set, you take its definition:
$\forall s \in S, (y \leq s \Rightarrow y \in S)$
and somehow turn it into coinitial:
$\forall y\in \mathbb{F}, (\exists s \in S, s \geq y)$.

I do not exactly see how one systematically creates the notion of co- for coinitial sets. And especially so for cofinal sets.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In this case, I think "co-" isn't used in the sense of duality, but rather as "together". A cofinal set is final with the base set, as in they reach equally far, "together".

Comment: What do you mean by "base set"?

Comment: In this case your ordered field, but the phrase is used in general with total orderings.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But still in general, I was asking "What's in a name?" and I still don't really get it. I can kind of hand-wave with "final" and "initial" but I am not sure where the "co" comes in.
The idea of "co" meaning together is helpful, but it does not completely clear it up.

Comment: It could just as well be called "final" rather than "cofinal". This practice was adopted by category theorists when they generalised the notion of a cofinal set to that of a [final functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor). In part, I suspect this is because of the confusion with the "co-" prefix. (Indeed, the dual of a final functor is an initial functor, which is called 'co-cofinal' by some authors.) I suspect that set theorists / order theorists chose "cofinal" over "final", since "final subset" could be confused with "terminal segment" (i.e. upwards-closed subset).

Comment: A thing about the intial = (a lower set) and coinitial = (opposite notion of cofinal) sets is that they do have this confusion.

Comment: Also, just as a side note, doesn't cofinal just mean unbounded? Or have I missed something in the definition?

Comment: Well, in a field it does. In a partially ordered set it does not. E.g. it can be bounded on one chain (linearly ordered subset) but not a cofinal subset. This is used in the definition of nets.

Comment: @Arthur: They're not the same in general. Consider the poset $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \star \}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has its usual order and $\star$ is not comparable to any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (so $\star \le \star$ but, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\star \not\le x$ and $x \not\le \star$). In this poset, $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded but not cofinal, since any cofinal subset must contain $\star$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I've mostly encountered cofinality in the context of total orders, but sure, in a poset they would be different, I can see that.

Comment: @Arthur: They're also different in any totally ordered set with a maximal element. In fact, in such posets, no subset is unbounded, but all subsets containing the maximal element are cofinal. However, they *do* coincide in totally ordered sets with no maximal element.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Yes, you're right, of course. Maximal elements make them different.

Comment: Cofinal means getting to the end together.  The odd integers and the even integers are cofinal.  Within omega_0 + omega_0, 1,2,3,.. is not cofinal.

Comment: "co-" here means the same thing as in "co-founder" or "co-conspirator" or "co-author" or "co-owner". $\qquad$

Comment: @CliveNewsted is your last statement above correct? What about $\omega=\omega_0$ as a subset of $\omega_1 = the first uncountable ordinal$? $\omega$ is unbounded but not a cofinal subset of $\omega_1$.